# FileNotFoundException with Pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I am running shell script with pig command

`pig -param_file some-filename` but I am getting following exception : `FileNotFoundException`. I checked and that file exists at the given location. What could  cause the problem ?

### Error before Pig is launched

```
ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File some-file.properties does not exist

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File some-file.properties does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFilesInternal(FileLocalizer.java:791)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFile(FileLocalizer.java:735)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.fetchRemoteParamFiles(Main.java:756)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:408)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Comment: The issue probably comes from the way you write your path. Can you give provide it or its scheme?

Comment: Could you also run `pwd` and `ls` from grunt ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
pig pathname/pig_file_name.pig
```

where pathname is  the location where you have your pig script file.

for example `pig C:\Users\Ren\Documents\Scripts\Weather_Analysis.pig`

Answer (score -1):

I think I had the same problem, I fixed it by doing this:

Give an absolute path to the properties file. The following worked for me:

```
pig -param_file /home/cloudera/Desktop/SOMELONGPATH/parameters.properties /home/cloudera/Desktop/SOMELONGPATHAGAIN/Flight.pig
```